# not only but also + negative sentence

Tags: grammar

I have a question. I am aware of using not only at the beginning of a sentence. However, I was wondering what happens if I have a negative sentence after both of them For example,

Not only, are not we able to do more than a certain number of tasks in a defined period of time, but also, our body is not capable of dealing with many tasks.

Is this ok?
Should I change the structure when I have a negative sentence?
Thank you in advance for your time friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify if possible.

"Not only are we unable to do more than a certain number of tasks ..."

"Not only are we not able" is technically correct but a bit clunky. "Not only are not we able" (which is what you have written here) would be incorrect.

Comment: The sentences were hypothetical.
I just wanted to be sure that there is nothing wrong with using a negative sentence after the not only.
So, I am going to do this:
If it were possible, I would simplify it, otherwise, I use the negative structure.

thank you for your help